# Python3 class function definition confusion about NameError

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter

I'm new to programming and this is my first post on the site. I'm sure I'm making a dumb mistake, but I'd really appreciate a push in the right direction. I'm trying to make a calculator, and want to make a function that produces a Button object for numbers. When I try to run this I get the error:

'NameError: name 'num_but_gen' is not defined'

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import * 

WINDOW_HEIGHT = 300
WINDOW_WIDTH = 325

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def num_but_gen(self, disp, xloc=0, yloc=0, wid=0, hei=0):
        self.Button(text='{}'.format(disp),height=hei, width=wid)
        self.place(x=xloc, y=yloc)

    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title('Calculator')
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        Button1 = num_but_gen('1', xloc=0, yloc=200, wid=40, hei=40)


root = Tk()
app = Window(root)
root.geometry("{}x{}".format(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT))
root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Also bonus points to anyone with suggestions on how to better phrase my question titles in future posts.

Comment: It's a method of your class.  You have to call it as `self.num_but_gen(...)`, just like you did with `init_window()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jasonharper is right, you need to add `self` in front of `num_but_gen`, but there are other problems in your code.

In `num_but_gen`:

- your window class does not have a `Button` attribute, so you need to remove `self.` in front of `Button`
- it is not the `Window` instance but the button that you want to place
- you don't need to use `text='{}'.format(disp)`, `text=disp` does the same.

In `init_window`:

- you store the result of `num_but_gen` in a variable, but this function returns nothing so that's useless (and capitalized names should not be used for variables, but for class names only)
- the width option of a button displaying text is in letters, not in pixels and its height option is in text lines, so `wid=40, hei=40` will create a very big button. If you want to set the button size in pixels, you can do it through the `place` method instead.

Here is the corresponding code:

```
import tkinter as tk

WINDOW_HEIGHT = 300
WINDOW_WIDTH = 325

class Window(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def num_but_gen(self, disp, xloc=0, yloc=0, wid=0, hei=0):
        button = tk.Button(self, text=disp)
        button.place(x=xloc, y=yloc, height=hei, width=wid)

    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title('Calculator')
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.num_but_gen('1', xloc=0, yloc=200, wid=40, hei=40)


root = tk.Tk()
app = Window(root)
root.geometry("{}x{}".format(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT))
root.mainloop()
```